# Adobe Flash Actionscript Augmented Reality object position relative to screen

Tags: flash, actionscript, position, transformation, augmented-reality

I have FLARManager library for my application which does the basic augmented reality using `FLARManagerTutorial_Collada.as` from its examples.
I want to have my cursor (or a movieclip) follow the imported 3D object on screen, but the cursors transformation is 2D and the object moves in 3D space. How can I do it?

```
this.modelContainer.transform = FLARPVGeomUtils.convertFLARMatrixToPVMatrix(this.activeMarker.transformMatrix);
```

This is transformation code for the 3D model container, but I don't know how to get the cursors X and Y values, as well as scale and/or rotation values from the 3D objects scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appeared to be easy.

```
private var activeMarker:FLARMarker;
```

`...`

```
var xPos:Number = this.activeMarker.centerpoint.x;
var yPos:Number = this.activeMarker.centerpoint.y;
var scale:Number = this.activeMarker.vector3D.z;
```

This will give X and Y screen position of the seen marker and using `this.activeMarker.vector3D.z`, one can get depth of the recognized marker which can also be represented as "scale".

The 3D Model Container `modelContainer` transformation is the same as the Marker `this.activeMarker` transformation, that's whated to know.

I found the answer here: [Inside FLARManager: 2D Marker Tracking](http://words.transmote.com/wp/flarmanager/inside-flarmanager/2d-marker-tracking/)